# Should I stick to Gaussian elimination or use old methods?

Tags: matrices

Doing 2x2 and 3x3 system of equations, I decided to try Gaussian elimination to solve these problems. So far I’ve understood perfectly this method, but I’m now wondering if there are any advantages of using this method instead of the old traditional ones?

Comment: It's applicable to all systems of linear equations ($n\times m$) and together with some pivot-strategies quite efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what "traditional" methods you have in mind. The advantages of Gaussian elimination is that it is a straightforward "deterministic" algorithm, it always gives you an exact answer in a finite number of steps, it is easily generalized to higher order systems of equations, and its computational complexity is quite easy to estimate.

On the other hand, it is not necessarily the most efficient way to solve a given problem. For example, you may be able to exploit symmetries of the system of equations to arrive at an answer more quickly and more simply than using Gaussian elimination.